# Linux NFS re-export

Tags: linux, nfs, aws

I am centralizing a Linux instance  in AWS as a file server hosting documents and other application files. Vpn tunnel  occurs from AWS Linux instance to on prem Linux Server. I am using NFS v4 to share files from AWS Linux file server to Linux on prem server.

I have 5 client computers that will connect to on prem Linux File Server. The AWS Linux instance that host the files will be mounted on the Linux on prem server.

How can I share the mount that is already mounted  on the Linux Server to my 5 clients computers? Re-mount using nfs?

Comment: Do you mean *"re"-export*?  (Are you trying to export a filesystem over NFS that you also mounted via NFS?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel NFS server cannot but [nfs-ganesha](https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki/PROXY) seems to be able to (I have not used it).

Other options involve NAT: (a) assign another IP address to the Linux on prem server and NAT connections to that IP to the AWS file server or (b) assign specific ports to the rpc demons (see [Running NFS Behind a Firewall](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-nfs-nfs-firewall-config.html) for an example) and NAT those ports (which prevents your on prem server from being an NFS server because you can't change which port NFS uses (2049)).

Comment: A proxy that is nfs-aware on both sides does not sound like a true re-export ... it could be suitable for solving the exact problem in the question details, but often re-exporting is desired to resolve protocol incompatibilities or establish security boundaries (eg by restricting a certain subnet to only get access to a subtree)